# Export Airflow run id , dag id ,execution date etc variable to Bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am developing data catalog for Analytics team and want to provide them view of Airflow job info including dag id ,execution,task status etc store into Bigquery Table and exposed as dashboard view.

Any suggestion how I should proceed with the design.Should I use Airflow CLI or Bashoperator to create the file and write into Bigquery.

Thanks

Comment: Did you already exported Airflow job info (dag id, execution, status, etc.) to file or you are asking for best solution for this? If so I assume this file is already in GCS? To write those info to BigQuery I'd suggest you to use `GCSToBigQueryOperator` or you have limitations that you can only use `Airflow CLI` or `Bashoperator`?

Comment: Did you already exported Airflow job info (dag id, execution, status, etc.) to file or you are asking for best solution for this? -  I am asking the best solution for this .

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, how you will export Airflow variables depends on you. As you mention, the main two ways are [Bash Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html) and [CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html). There already was a similar question which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53206003/export-all-airflow-variables) with some additional information.

When you will get this file I'd suggest you save it in `Google Cloud Storage` and then use [GCSToBigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/gcs.html#gcstobigqueryoperator).